# How to make a FORM PUT request through rxjs ajax?

Tags: ajax, rxjs5

Jquery request objects have a property by the name 'data' which is used to set form data and make a form request with the right headers.

I wanted to achieve the same in rxjs ajax but could not find a way. 
The only exhaustive list of request configuration properties I could find was this https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/ajax.md

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for RxJS5 is not complete yet on that part, but you can use it as follows:

```
 import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
 import "rxjs/add/observable/dom/ajax";

 const url = "http://my-site.org/some/endpoint";
 const request$ = Observable.ajax.put(url, {a: "test"});
 request$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

And of course all other REST-methods are available

```
  Observable.ajax(urlOrRequest: string | AjaxRequest): Observable<AjaxResponse>;
  Observable.ajax.get(url: string, headers?: Object): Observable<AjaxResponse>;
  Observable.ajax.post(url: string, body?: any, headers?: Object): Observable<AjaxResponse>;
  Observable.ajax.put(url: string, body?: any, headers?: Object): Observable<AjaxResponse>;
  Observable.ajax.patch(url: string, body?: any, headers?: Object): Observable<AjaxResponse>;
  Observable.ajax.delete(url: string, headers?: Object): Observable<AjaxResponse>;
  Observable.ajax.getJSON<T>(url: string, headers?: Object): Observable<T>;
```

If you want to send a fully custom ajax-request, you can use the following interface:

```
interface AjaxRequest {
  url?: string;
  body?: any;
  user?: string;
  async?: boolean;
  method?: string;
  headers?: Object;
  timeout?: number;
  password?: string;
  hasContent?: boolean;
  crossDomain?: boolean;
  withCredentials?: boolean;
  createXHR?: () => XMLHttpRequest;
  progressSubscriber?: Subscriber<any>;
  responseType?: string;
}
```

All take from here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/0ab1d3b4d1178a1d31c49c737832cde767da3fb1/src/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts